# jQuery carousel which allows for (not overlaid) text next to image

Tags: jquery, carousel

I spent some time looking around for a (jquery) carousel or slideshow. There are hundreds out there, and many of them really astonishing.

But what I need, is a carousel where say, two thirds of the horizontal space are taken up by the image, and one third by text. The text shouldn't be an overlay on the image.

So far, I only found [Sliderion](http://slidorion.com/), bxSlider and [EvoSlider](http://codecanyon.net/item/evo-slider-pro-jquery-slider-plugin/full_screen_preview/1967625?ref=lvraa) (which is what I really like; but it's not free. Ok, it's neither expensive either.)

Do you know of any other scripts which fulfill these requirements?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is nivoSlider. It's free and easy to start with, give a try and look the examples:

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/

Comment: Great, thanks. Nice example with text overlay here: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/image-slider-photoshop-jquery-nivo-slider/

Answer (score 1):

Try **[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)**

It's a nifty carousel which works on list elements. You can style the contents inside of the list items to your specifications:

**HTML**

```
<ul id='carousel'>
    <li>
        <img src='url goes here' />
        <p>text goes here</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src='url goes here' />
        <p>text goes here</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li img, ul li p { display: inline; }
ul li img { width: 66%; }
ul li p { width: 33%; }
```